# Preventing multiple python scripts from crashing with single shell script?

Tags: shell-script, python, raspberry-pi

I would like to create a shell script to prevent a python script from crashing in a Raspberry Pi. This python script is auto started on reboot with cron, however, sometimes it can crash while running.

Currently my shell script reads:

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMAND='python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript.py'
LOGFILE=restart.txt

writelog() {
  now=`date`
  echo "$now $*" >> $LOGFILE
}

writelog "Starting"
while true ; do
  $COMMAND
  writelog "Exited with status $?"
  writelog "Restarting"
done
```

I wanted to ask if I can create two command lines, in order to make sure two independent scripts can be prevented from crashing with this shell script? Or do I have to make a new shell script file for the second python script?

I am thinking of modifying it this way:

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMAND1='python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript1.py'
COMMAND2='python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript2.py'
LOGFILE=restart.txt

writelog() {
  now=`date`
  echo "$now $*" >> $LOGFILE
}

writelog "Starting"
while true ; do
  $COMMAND1
  $COMMAND2
  writelog "Exited with status $?"
  writelog "Restarting"
  done
```

Would this modification work? I appreciate any advice as I am still quite new to the linux (debian) platform.

Comment: Your sigle-script approach will start `COMMAND1`, wait for it to terminate, then start `COMMAND2`, and also wait for it to terminate, before it repeats that cycle. Are you sure this is intended?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this. This is not what I intended. I would like that either of the scripts be terminated (not both), and the cycle to be repeated. That way, both python scripts would keep running. So it seems that I might have to create two separate shell scripts for each? Or is there another way I can modify this shell script?

Comment: The exact implementation depends on how the two processes depend on each other. If one crashes or otherwise terminates, should the other be terminated and restarted, too? If it can just run along, then probably two independent scripts would be the most straight-forward solution. In short, try to nail down your *complete* requirements first, then you'll probably get a better idea how to handle restarting. Make a list, check it for being complete and consistent, then come back and update your question if you still need help with that.

Comment: BTW, please also take the time to take the [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the tour as suggested. As to your previous post, I agree that having two independent scripts might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using systemd you could create a service for each command, then get systemd to restart it if it crashes.

Something like:

```
[Unit]
Description='description of script'

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/too/script
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This can then be put into `/etc/systemd/system`, after running `systemctl daemon-reload` you will be able to start the service. It will also start after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I remember testing out a couple of approach back then and found the shell script method the most reliable. I might also have tried the systemd approach but I can't remember now. But I'll give this approach a try. Thanks!

Comment: If I have two scripts that I want to ensure that they would always be running, do I just stack one service on top of the other? like:`[Service]
ExecStart=/path/too/script1
Restart=always [Service]
ExecStart=/path/too/script2
Restart=always`

Comment: No you would create a separate service for each script, this will also allow you to stop and start them independently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle an arbitrary number of asynchronous processes
from one control script, you can use this approach:

```
#!/bin/sh
COMMAND1=(python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript1.py)
COMMAND2=(python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript2.py)
    ︙
rm -f COMMAND1_failed; ("${COMMAND1[@]}"; touch COMMAND1_failed)&
rm -f COMMAND2_failed; ("${COMMAND2[@]}"; touch COMMAND2_failed)&
       ︙
while true
do
        if [ -e COMMAND1_failed ]
        then
                # Restart Command1
                rm -f COMMAND1_failed; ("${COMMAND1[@]}"; touch COMMAND1_failed)&
        fi
        if [ -e COMMAND2_failed ]
        then
                # Restart Command2
                rm -f COMMAND2_failed; ("${COMMAND2[@]}"; touch COMMAND2_failed)&
        fi
         ︙
        sleep 60
done
```

- `COMMAND1=(python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript1.py)`
  defines `COMMAND1` to be an array. 
  This allows the command to include words that contain spaces;
  for example, something like
  `COMMAND1=(python "home/pi/projects/my python script1.py")`.
- `"${COMMAND1[@]}"` is analogous to your use of `$COMMAND1`;
  it runs your first command, quoting its constituent words.
- `(commandA; commandB)`
  essentially creates an ad-hoc two-line script:

  ```
  commandA
  commandB
  ```

  so `("${COMMAND1[@]}"; touch COMMAND1_failed)` says
  “run command #1, wait for it to finish,
  and then touch (create) a file called `COMMAND1_failed`. 
  This entire mini-script runs in the background,
  so the main script can go on and run command #2, etc.
- Realistically,
  you should probably use full pathnames for the `failed` files,
  and maybe put their names into variables.
- After starting all the background jobs,
  the main script enters an infinite (forever) loop. 
  If the `COMMAND1_failed` file exists,
  that means that command #1 and needs to be restarted. 
  Etc.
- Adjust the `sleep` as desired. 
  Too low a value, and the control script might run so often
  that it affects the performance of the system. 
  Too high a value and the asynchronous tasks will not be restarted promptly,
  so the responsiveness of the system would suffer in that way.

The above starts all the processes,
and then enters an infinite loop. 
Here is a trivial optimization:

```
#!/bin/sh
    ︙
touch COMMAND1_failed
       ︙
while true
do
        if [ -e COMMAND1_failed ]
        then
                # (Re)start Command1
                rm -f COMMAND1_failed; ("${COMMAND1[@]}"; touch COMMAND1_failed)&
        fi
         ︙
        sleep 60
done
```

which starts the background processes on the first iteration of the loop,
after creating all the necessary `COMMANDn_failed` files
to make it look like the processes need to be (re)started. 
The only difference is that it lists the commands to start the processes 
once instead of twice.

See also:

- [Group a set of processes such that when one dies,
  so do all the other processes in that group](https://superuser.com/q/1234316/354511). 
  In particular, [Kamil Maciorowski’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1234316/354511#1234467)
  partially inspired my answer here.
- [How should I check whether a given PID is running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294984/80216)
- [Running a script when background process crashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391721/80216)
- [Given two background commands,
  terminate the remaining one when either exits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231676/80216)

Comment: Thanks G-Man. I wanted to ask a few questions with regards to your suggestion.

Comment: 1) With regards to the minor optimisation code that you also posted, what would be the benefit of using that compared to the previous one?

Comment: 2) I noticed `︙` in your code, what are these? Are they placeholder code?

Comment: 3)When I ran the script, I've got this error for the COMMAND1 and COMMAND2 lines
`constantrun.sh: 4: constantrun.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` so I changed the brackets to `''`. So that line now reads:`COMMAND1='python /home/pi/TESA/outdoor_status_SQL_v01.py'`

Comment: I then ran the script again, and I got `constantrun.sh: 7: constantrun.sh: Bad substitution constantrun.sh: 8: constantrun.sh: Bad substitution` What is this bad subsitution error and how can I resolve it? I think it is referring to these two lines `rm -f COMMAND1_failed; ("${COMMAND1[@]}"; touch COMMAND1_failed)& rm -f COMMAND2_failed; ("${COMMAND2[@]}"; touch COMMAND2_failed)&`.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. (1) I have updated the answer. (2) Yes, `︙` is three dots, like `...` only vertical.  It means “and so on, more of the same”. (3) `variable=(word1 word2 word3)` creates an array variable.  I don’t know why that didn’t work for you; maybe if you post the *exact* command you had on line 4, I can help.  The `"${COMMAND1[@]}"` syntax expands an array variable; by changing the variable back to a simple string, you broke line 7.  Please post the code that got the line 4 error ***in your question*** (edit your question).